# Can we say that conclusion in this argument: (P v Q), P |- Q breaks "The Law of Excluded Middle"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Can we say that the conclusion in this argument: **(P v Q), P |- Q** breaks  "The Law of Excluded Middle"? And that is the reason why argument is invalid?

I recently studied "The Law of Excluded Middle":

> In logic, the law of excluded middle (or the principle of excluded middle) states that for any proposition, either that proposition is true or its negation is true. [Wiki](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwidyKXpvbvgAhUIMo8KHQB4ABUQFjACegQIABAK&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLaw_of_excluded_middle&usg=AOvVaw2J6eRkN9-C5qx0kl01Bo_k)

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
p&q&p∨ q\\ \hline
T&T&T\\
T&F&T\\
F&T&T\\
F&F&F\\\hline
\end{array}$$

"The following argument: **(P v Q), P |- Q** is invalid. Because,

**Premise 1:** there are **three** instance in truth table where **(P v Q)** is **True** (1st three in above table),

**Premise 2:** there are **two** instance in truth table where **(P)** is True for **(P v Q)** to be **true** at the same time (1st two in above table),

**Conclusion:** In this scenario **Q** is both True and False for (P) and (P v Q) to be true, right? and that is the reason why this **argument is invalid**.

Comment: Your judgement (P v Q), P |- Q holds neither in classical logic nor in intuitionistic logic.

Comment: @IlyaVlasov well, that is what I have already stated. My question is different :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The law of the excluded middle has nothing to do with why this argument is false. The law of the excluded middle says that $P \lor \lnot P$ is always true, but even in logics that do *not* have that law, you cannot conclude $Q$ from $P$ and $P \lor Q$.

Using your truth table interpretation of $\vdash$, the reason $P, P \lor Q \vdash Q$ is false is that there is a line in the truth table where $P$ and $P \lor Q$ are true, but $Q$ is false, namely, the second one.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to logic and trying to understand core concepts  :)